# Нуно получить значения с БД, и записать в табличку WInForms

Tags: c++, json

мой первый опыт работы программистом был сегодня.  И работодатель поставил мне задачу:
1) Создать на WinForms меню проекта, где будет присутствовать табличка  с данными.
2) Данные должны будут считываться с сервера, и показываться в нашей табличке по запросу пользователя.
3) Надо использовать Json и C++.

Первую часть задания я сделал относительно быстро. Не был знаком с формами, но за несколько часов изучил, и сделал внешний вид приложения. Теперь пытаюсь понять, как мне испоьзовать Json в C++. Я прочитал про Json, и насколько понял он работает с JavaScript.  О том как использовать его в сях я не нашел. Кроме того работодатель не сказал явно, как хранится БД и что для этого используется. Поэтому я немного в ступоре.

Вопрос 1.  Как получить значения(Строку) из рандомной БД в С++
Вопрос 2.  Каким образом Json использовать в С++, и зачем мне это надо, если с сервера я все равно получу строку, и могу запихнуть эту строку в табличку?

Comment: 1.можно использовать ODBC или использовать набор бибилиотек для конкретной субд. 2. JSON это формат данных, вам с сервера придут данные в JSON формате, из которого их надо достать с помощью одной из библиотек (rapidJson, yajl...)

Comment: Спасибо, я уже освоил библиотеку под MS SQL, написал код, приложение запускается но теперь проблема с доступом к моей БД, которая поставлена на Виртулке. Никак не могу найти где в MS SQL Server 2000 давать доступ по TCP/IP